# Python GTK+ 3 - Can't set a parent on a toplevel widget

Tags: python, pygtk

```
Gtk-WARNING **: 19:18:52.313: Can't set a parent on a toplevel widget
```

Why do I get this warning? Isn't master win a toplevel widget? What am I doing wrong?
Shouldn't master_win be toplevel? It is created first...

```
class PluginWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(title="Stack Demo")
        #some stuff

master_win = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
master_win.set_policy(Gtk.PolicyType.NEVER, Gtk.PolicyType.ALWAYS)
win = PluginWindow()
master_win.add(win)
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
master_win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the order wrong

```
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

class PluginWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(title="Stack Demo")
        #some stuff

master_win = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
master_win.set_policy(Gtk.PolicyType.NEVER, Gtk.PolicyType.ALWAYS)
win = PluginWindow()
win.add(master_win)
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add a Gtk.Window() object into Gtk.ScrolledWindow() object and that is not possible. It's inversed.

A Gtk.Window is a toplevel window which can contain other widgets. Windows normally have decorations that are under the control of the windowing system and allow the user to manipulate the window (resize it, move it, close it,…).

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk


class PluginWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(title="Stack Demo")
        # some stuff


master_win = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
master_win.set_policy(Gtk.PolicyType.NEVER, Gtk.PolicyType.ALWAYS)
win = PluginWindow()
# Gtk.ScrolledWindow added to Gtk.Window
win.add(master_win)
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```